# C++ mathematical arrays library

Tags: software-development, library, c++, math

Can anybody here recommend a good C++ arrays library, for 1, 2 and 3 dimensional arrays, that has the following features:

- The rank is specified at compile time, like in C++ AMP [*Nice to have, but not really required*]
- Works with Visual C++ 2013.
- Can wrap a chunk of memory, like C++ AMP array_view. I can specify my own storage order.
- Performs component-wise operations and vector math without allocating temporary arrays (like Eigen/Blaze/Armadillo expression templates)
- Can slice arrays in any dimension and create a view of that array, like in MATLAB. For example: `A(i,:,j)`.
- Uses enhanced CPU instructions, like SSE/SSE2/AVX for fast performance and has a cache-friendly implementation.
- Does not need any "heavy weight" external library, like NumPy or MATLAB's C libraries.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to ask at the new Code Recommendations on Area51 - "Proposed Q&A site for programmers seeking the best library for specific tasks" area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66606/code-recommendations

Comment: The questions there are very short. I cannot state the requirements from my library, like I did here. Unless I am missing something?

Comment: Note that many see [the Code Recommendations proposal](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/13864/this-is-a-duplicate-of-software-recommendations) as a duplicate of software recommendations. This question is perfectly on-topic here.

Comment: Eigen is only for 2d arrays. I want more dimensions. I want at least 3